# Cursor vs FOR Loop in Oracle

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

So I have a block of PLSQL code that will drop all indexes as shown in the following block of code:

```
DECLARE
DRP_STMNT   VARCHAR2(100) := ''; 
BEGIN
    FOR I IN (SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM USER_INDEXES) LOOP
        DRP_STMNT := 'DROP INDEX ' || I.INDEX_NAME;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DRP_STMNT;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

That will do the job but should I use a cursor instead of embedding my SELECT statement within the FOR LOOP?

Does the FOR LOOP look at the entire table or does it process one row at a time?

What do you guys suggest using and why?

Comment: There's no need to use an explicit cursor here.

Comment: @APC would that be the same case if I want to create it as a stored procedure?

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Every select **is** a (implicit) cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result will be just the same.

Though, you'll consume some more energy as you'd have to type more characters as you have to declare a cursor and cursor variable, open a cursor, start the loop, fetch from it, take care about exiting the loop, close a cursor.

When you use a cursor FOR loop (as you did), there's much less typing as Oracle does lots of that for you. For free.

Comment: But will what I have right now perform the same way as if I had a cursor (which is basically pointing at each row at a time)?

Comment: You'd be doing it one-by-one either way, no difference.

Comment: @Littlefoot that's not strictly true; Oracle can and will turn cursor for loops into `fetch ... bulk collect limit 100` style loops behind the scenes, assuming the plsql_optimize_level is >=2. For the OP: it doesn't matter whether the cursor is explicitly (`declare cursor some_curosr is ...; begin for rec in some_cursor loop ...`) or implicitly `for rec in (select ....) loop`, the behaviour of the loop is the same.

Comment: Ah! That's for *advanced* users, @Boneist. Didn't know that (obviously, I'm not that *advanced* person). Thank you!

Comment: @Littlefoot every day is a learning day *{:-) And now you are an advanced user, under your definition!